# value_counts in a weighted manner with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have pandas dataframe such as

```
basket_id = [1,2,3,4,5]
continents = ['apple', 'apple orange', 'apple orange pear', 'pear apple', 'pear']
df = pd.DataFrame({'basket_id' : basket_id , 'continents ' : continents })
```

baskets are equal, say 18kg, and each basket has an equal amount from each of its fruits: basket 2 has 9kg apple and 9kg orange.

I want to know how much I have from each fruit. if each basket has only one type of fruit I could simply apply `value_counts` and multiply by 18. But now how could I get my answer?

I expect the following:

```
fruits = ['apple', 'orange', 'pear']
amounts = [42, 15, 33]
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'fruits' : fruits , 'amounts(kg)' : amounts })
df1
```

apples are 42kg: 18kg from basket 1, 9kg of basket 2, 6kg of basket 3, and 9kg of basket 4.

Comment: Can you post the expected output to the question?

Comment: `df["continents"].str.split().explode().value_counts()` would get the value counts by fruit if thats what you are after.

Comment: @Ch3steR  I posted the expected output.

Comment: @NiklasMertsch Every library in python is ok. Could you please write the answer?

Comment: @moshtaba Thank you. Now the question is clear. Posted an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Series.str.split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) then [`Series.explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.explode.html) now count how many fruits are in a basket using [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.transform.html) then use [`Series.rdiv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.rdiv.html) to get relative weights in each basket, then groupby each fruit and take the sum.

```
out = df['continents'].str.split().explode()
amt = out.groupby(level=0).transform('count').rdiv(18).groupby(out).sum()

apple     42.0
orange    15.0
pear      33.0
Name: continents , dtype: float64
```

To get exact output as mentioned in question, you have to use `Series.reset_index` then `Series.rename`

```
amt.reset_index(name='amounts(kg)').rename(columns={'index':'fruit'})

    fruit  amounts(kg)
0   apple         42.0
1  orange         15.0
2    pear         33.0
```

Answer (score 0):

So for each N items in a basket you want to add 18/N kg of each item? You can use a `defaultdict(int)`, which generates default values for unknown entries by calling `int()` (which is 0) and add the amounts to that.

```py
baskets = ['apple', 'apple orange', 'apple orange pear', 'pear apple', 'pear']

from collections import defaultdict

amounts = defaultdict(int)
for basket in baskets:
    items = basket.split()
    for item in items:
        amounts[item] += 18 // len(items)

print(amounts)
# defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {'apple': 42, 'orange': 15, 'pear': 33})

# if you need a pandas output
import pandas as pd

print(pd.Series(amounts))
# apple     42
# orange    15
# pear      33
# dtype: int64
```